# Numerical solution of an ODE system of equations using RK4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have given an assignment to find the solution to the ODE system of equations as follow:

$$\begin{cases} x_1' = x_1 + x_2 \\ x_2' = -3x_1 -10x_2 + x_2 ^2\end{cases}$$

With initial conditions: $x_1(0) = 1, \quad x_2(0)=10$ on interval $[0,10]$

The above system of questions differs in two aspects from the normal questions of my textbook so I am confused and don't know how to program the algorithm in Matlab:

1. It has two intermingled equations. In contrary to textbook samples which has only one in form of: $x'=f(t,x)$
2. $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ don't have any $t$ variable! which makes me even more confused.

I appreciate it if you elaborate  on the above two points. Thanks.

------------------------------------------Part2-----------------------------------------

Ok with above clarifications I started to program in Matlab, after running my code, $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ seems to change (probably becomes unstable) after changing the step number which changes h respectively.

Here is the code:

```
function [sol_x1, sol_x2] = rk4 (m)
    a = 0;      % interval = [a, b] = [0, 10]
    b = 10;
    h = (b-a) / m; % m is  number of steps

    Sx1 = zeros (1,m+1);      % Solutions will be saved here
    Sx2 = zeros (1,m+1);

    Sx1(1) = 1;    % initial values
    Sx2(1) = 10;

    for j = 1:m
        x1 = Sx1(j);
        x2 = Sx2(j);

        fprintf('x1 = %i, x2 = %i \n', x1, x2);

        x1_k1 = h * f1(x1, x2);
        x2_k1 = h * f2(x1, x2);

        x1_k2 = h * f1(x1 + x1_k1/2, x2 + x2_k1/2);
        x2_k2 = h * f2(x1 + x1_k1/2, x2 + x2_k1/2);

        x1_k3 = h * f1(x1 + x1_k2/2, x2 + x2_k2/2);
        x2_k3 = h * f2(x1 + x1_k2/2, x2 + x2_k2/2);

        x1_k4 = h * f1(x1 + x1_k3, x2 + x2_k3);
        x2_k4 = h * f2(x1 + x1_k3, x2 + x2_k3);


        next_x1 = x1 + (x1_k1 + (2 * x1_k2) + (2 * x1_k3) + x1_k4) / 6;
        next_x2 = x2 + (x2_k1 + (2 * x2_k2) + (2 * x2_k3) + x2_k4) / 6;

        % no need for t = t + h because x1 and x2 do not depend on t

        %Save the solutions
        fprintf('%i\n', h);
        %display(h)
        Sx1(j+1) = next_x1;
        Sx2(j+1) = next_x2;
    end    

    sol_x1 = Sx1;
    sol_x2 = Sx2;
end

function [y] = f1 (x1, x2) 
    y = x1 + x2;
end

function [y] = f2 (x1, x2) 
    y = (-3 * x1) + (-10 * x2) + (x2 ^ 2);
end
```

Am I on right path?

$x1(t)$ and $x2(t)$ shoots up to very large numbers pretty quickly. I think something is wrong with my algorithm implementation.

Comment: Presumaby there is a $t$ variable, and $x_1'$ means $\dfrac{dx_1(t)}{dt}$. $\qquad$

Comment: I agree; I think the OP is confused because the equations are separable (I think that is the term)

Comment: yes I know that, but $t$ does not appear in RHS as an effective variable, like $x_1' = x_1 + x_2 + tcos(t)$

Comment: This is true, but that isn't necessary in general. Think of a constant function $f(t)=2$ -- there's no explicit t-dependence, but it is still written "as a function of t".

Comment: Rather than working componentwise as you did here, you can work in vector form, using a function that takes a vector and returns a vector. In this case it would be f(x)=[x(1)+x(2);-3*x(1)-10*x(2)+x(2)^2] You could then write a Matlab implementation exactly like the case for a single ODE because Matlab treats vectors almost exactly the same as it treats numbers.

Comment: Also, I just did the same problem with ode45 and you do indeed get fairly large numbers, on the order of $10^4$ for $x_1$ and $10^2$ for $x_2$

Comment: lan: Wow ! yes !! I increased the $m$ to $10^4$ and I can plot the function and see its curve correctly. 100 iterations or even 1,000 iterations won't work. lan: my brain has difficulty with vectors, that is why I keep them separate to make things clear, but I will put your advise into practice soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally, you have a problem with the line

```
h = h + step
```

while you use `h` as step size. Since originally `step = h` you get a rapidly growing step size where it should be constant. What you probably meant was

```
t = t + h
```

there is no need for the extra `step` variable. Also, consider using `h=(b-a)/m` for greater flexibility, using a single point of constant definition.

---

Everything else is looking good. You can always test for reliability of the code by varying the step size. The numerical results should stay stable with small variations.

Comment: I think my code is fine. If $m=100$ then $h=0.1$. Therefore, in the for loop $h$ will be increase by '$step = h = 0.1$' variable per each iteration which is correct. I double check by printing $h$ in each iteration and it does not grow rapidly. The problem is somewhere else. After following your correction and adding $x$ it even  grows faster!

Comment: Though h=(b-a)/m point is valid, I will add it to the code.

Comment: No, `h` should be constant, there should be **no** increase during the loop. Or replace `h` by `step` in the computation of the `x_k`.

Comment: Oh I see ! ok I'll fix.

Comment: It is near zero till iteration 55/100 and then suddenly jump up, and rapidly increases. It might be the behavior that my instructor wants me to observe. I am not sure though.

Comment: The $+x_2^2$ in the second equation is what is called "positive feedback" and can lead to exploding solutions. The larger $x_2$ gets, the faster it grows. The simple example for this behavior is $u'=u^2$.

Comment: Increasing the steps to the order of $10^4$ and more solved the issue now, I can see the answer. thank you! Plus "positive feedback" also is a new term for me, thanks for teaching me.

Comment: I don't think the rapid growth here is due to the nonlinearity, I think it is mostly just caused by the exponential growth of $x_1$.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of this system of differential equations as ${\bf x}' = f({\bf x},t)$ where ${\bf x}$ is the vector $\pmatrix{x_1\cr x_2\cr}$, and 
$$ f\left(\pmatrix{x_1\cr x_2\cr},t\right) = \pmatrix{x_1 + x_2\cr −3 x_1−10 x_2+x_2^2}$$
The fact that this doesn't happen to depend on $t$ makes no difference.  The fact that $\bf x$  is a vector rather than a scalar also doesn't matter: the RK4 formulas are exactly the same as in the scalar case.

Comment: Your answer cleared my confusion, but I still can't get the code working properly, I deeply appreciate it if you look at  my code and see where I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the notation $f(x,t)$ is for completeness, in the sense that it is also meant to cover cases where there is no explicit $t$ dependence.

As for the other part of your question, you can write

\begin{align}
x_1' & = f_1(x_1,x_2,t) = \cdots \\
x_2' & = f_2(x_1,x_2,t) = \cdots
\end{align}

If you want me to see if I can find some examples online, or write some pseudo-code, I can do that for you.

Comment: Let me try myself first. I will post it here and then you can fix my errors and then the future users can have a guide to follow when then hit such systems of equations.

Comment: I posted the code, I appreciate if you check.